# Criteria when using libraries - use Library's data type VS create my own type?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, maintainability

I am coding a game that use many open-source libraries, each library has its own type for representing 3D vector :-

- **Bullet** (a Physics engine library) : **Vector3**.
- **Ogre** (a 3D rendering library) : **Ogre::Vector3**.
- **Eigen** (a matrix manipulation library) : **Vector3d**.

Even those libraries are popular-and-high-quality, but I don't want to depend on those too much.

Thus, I have decided to create my own type named **Vect3**, and create convertors between them.

It suits my demand very well because my game logic want to manipulate Vector 3D.

It makes sense especially in a scope that **Vect3** doesn't related to physics,rendering or matrix manipulation at all.

### Problem

I am coding an AI module, which heavily use **Eigen**.
For a prototype, I use **Eigen::MatrixXf** a lot.
**MatrixXf** is a far more complex structure comparing to **Vector3**.

I plan to create my own class **MyMatrix** and refactor the AI to use **MyMatrix** instead of **Eigen::MatrixXf**.

I doubt whether it is a good decision.
In other words, should I create my own datatype for everything I see and want to use?

### Question

What are the criteria to pick one of these choices for a type that already exists in one or more external libraries?
**A.** The type should be created as a new class.
**B.** Use library type (and which one?).

### My current criteria

- (Strong) How much the type related to a certain library?  Highly related = **B.**
- (Strong) How generous of the license of the library?  Generous = **B.**
- (Medium) How complex is a type?  Complex = **B.**
- (Weak) How much speed I need?   Conversion costs some CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Robert C. Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin) said in his Book, Clean Code:
It is always a good practice to wrap 3rd Party Code.
Mike Finney quotes Martin in his [Blog](http://smilingfinney.blogspot.de/2008/11/wrapping-3rd-party-code-is-clean-code.html) and summarize it:

> - The third party code can evolve
> - Your wrapper's interface can be made to precisely suit your application's needs

in your situation, i would write my own classes to wrap the vector and matrices library classes.
Another advantage is that your code is only dependent on what it really needs.

Comment: Your answer is concise and complete. Thank!